# Find largest total distance across 5 points in N points dataset

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

The problem I'm trying to solve involves a dataset of roughly 5000 GPS points and the task to find the 5 points within that dataset that result in the largest overall distance.

[image: Sketch]

(Note that Start and End are not necessarily at the same location)

The naive solution would be five nested loops that iterate over all the points in the dataset until the largest total distance is found, but that is unpractical given that the distance calculation is somewhat slow:

```
for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  pointA = points[i];

  for (j = i; j < points.length; j++) {
    pointB = points[j];
    distanceAB = distance(pointA, pointB);

    for (k = j; k < points.length; k++) {
      pointC = points[k];
      distanceBC = distance(pointB, pointC);

      // ...

      score = distanceAB + distanceBC + distanceCD + distanceDE;
      if (score > winner.score) {
        // save new winner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem that needs to do less work?

Comment: Do you need to find a longest simple path with 5 vertices?

Comment: If the distance computation is slow you can just cache those results. It should "only" need about 12.5 million values.

Comment: @DAle that sounds roughly like what I'm trying to do, yes

Comment: @HansOlsson since the distance calculations are only used a couple of times each I don't think caching will make a big different. my guess is that an algorithm with a better algorithmic complexity will make a much larger difference. "20143" is actually not possible since the points we look for need to be ordered like in the dataset.

Comment: @TBieniek you should definitely mention "the points we look for need to be ordered like in the dataset" in the question.

Comment: "the points we look for need to be ordered like in the dataset". Wow, that changes everything.

Comment: I've added a sketch to the question which should hopefully make it easier to understand

Comment: Your picture doesn't correspond to the code. Do you need to maximize `AB+BC+CD+DE` or `AB+BC+CD+DE+EA`?

Comment: right, sorry, I counted incorrectly :D  the picture shows the situation for 6 points with overlapping A and F, not 5 points. 

Comment: But how can the last point be the same as the first one if they are "ordered"? The details are important in this case.

Comment: @DAle the XY coords of the point are the same or roughly similar, but it is a different point

Comment: @TBieniek, ok,  then the first part of my answer seems to be correct for your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

**Non closed ordered path with 5 points**

If the points in the path should be ordered, then you need to find the longest path in a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) with fixed number of edges. This can be done by simple [dynamic programming](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/) algorithm. The recurrence is
[image]

The answer will be: `max(f(i,4))`.

**Closed ordered path with 5 points**

If we need to find a closed path like on your picture (with ordered points), then for every `start` point we need to find the values of this function:
[image]

The maximal length of the closed path with `start` as the starting point will be
`longest(start) = max(f(i,4) + dist(i,start))`.

Thus, the answer will be: `max(longest(start))`.